# How does does the "Sign out all other sessions" feature work in Gmail?

Tags: authentication, cookies, session-management, google

In Gmail, at the bottom of the screen if you click Details it will show you your recent account activity and there's a button to sign you out of all other sessions. How does this work? Are they somehow revoking cookies from the server side?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty simple task to accomplish.

Basically the server will store the session IDs of each individual active session in a database somewhere. Revoking a particular session is a simple task of removing the record from the database, which will invalidate the session.

Comment: Any idea how you'd accomplish this in ASP.NET?

Comment: @John I don't write ASP.NET code so I am unable to comment on a direct implementation. That said, it has nothing to do with which programming language/framework you use.

Comment: Hmm I guess the ASP.NET implementation is probably a question better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? This wouldn't scale very well. If you have to validate the user session on every call you would have to make a DB request on every user request which means your DB would have to scale at the same size as your API endpoints scale to handle the one to one load.